# Tomcat raises encryption exception

Tags: tomcat, java, jce

I recently installed jdk 1.6. My tomcat installation started raising the following error.

org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine

I have the JCE files in jre/lib/security directory despite what is mentioned in the error message. What could possibly be the problem? What should I do to get it fixed? Thanks

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:832)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:679)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:473)
at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72)
at com.pagatech.services.util.StatefulEncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(StatefulEncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:57)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperty(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:121)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:81)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: what sais java -version?

Comment: There are always JCE files in /lib/security, but are they actually the unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files?

Comment: @DonQuixote no, what a vendor, SUN? OpenJDK?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I have replaced them with the unlimited version but the problem still exists

Comment: Could you post the actual exception / entire stacktrace?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I posted the stack trace.

Comment: @DonQuixote Install them in the JDK directory too. I believe Tomcat executes via a JDK not a JRE.